The executable only works when the DLLs are in the same folder
I have noticed that my executable only works when it's in the same folder as the DLL files it's dependent on. I know if I put the DLL file in system32 folder my executable will work without having the DLL file in the same folder. However, I was wondering if it's possible to put the DLLs and the executable in different folders. I am using CMake and it will be very helpful since my build folder is kinda getting messy.
So far I have only managed to put the DLL files in system32 folder.

Your DLL must be in either the folder or in the search path for DLLs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Life is easiest for developers (and customers) when all the EXEs and DLLs are in the same directory.

EXE can call SetDllDirectory to add one more DLL directory to the search path.

When it comes time to distribute your program, you absolutely should be using an installer builder (like NSIS, Inno Setup, InstallForge, Install Shield, WiX, etc), which you can instruct to either add DLLs to the system (if necessary) or keep them in your .exe’s folder.
